# Victory Native PieChart titles nested

Tags: react-native, pie-chart, victory-native

I am using victory-native chart to render a pie chart but titles nested.Here is my code:

```
  <VictoryPie
            animate={{
              duration: 1000,
              easing: 'bounce',
            }}
            labelPosition={({index}) => 'centroid'}
            labels={({datum}) => datum.x}
            width={width - 100}
            labelComponent={<VictoryLabel textAnchor={'end'} angle={45} />}
            theme={VictoryTheme.material}
            data={categorySumSales}
          />
```

My PieChart:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUDEU.jpg)

This PieChart, i want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iTd7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to avoid labels overlapping each other is to develop a custom [labelComponent](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-pie/#labelcomponent) which accounts for relative position of each label to the chart, and renders labels in a non-overlapping way.

That's too hard, since all you really want is to display a name of each data slice. Using [legend](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-legend/) is a much easier way to achieve that.